# onKeyDown event not fired for some character keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

In my webpage I have a div, for which `onkeydown` event is handled. The `onkeydown` event is fired for keyboard keys character key 'z','a','p' etc. But the for the character key such as 'x','f','m','q' etc event is not fired . After pressing character key'f' I could see that the focus moves to the next element. Anyone please explain how this occur?

I could see the same happens  in  Chrome (version: 32)  , IE (version:11) , Firefox (version:27)

Comment: it will be very good with some demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some keys might be used for some default operation by a browser. For example Enter submits a form in whitch the div is in IE. Try to use e.preventDefault(); before your own event code. Try the code below.

```
$(document).on("keydown", "mydiv", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```